# Do a Krynn Minotaur Monk's Horns Count as Magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, unearthed-arcana, natural-weapon, minotaur

At 6th level all of a monk's unarmed strikes count as magical. Does this benefit also apply to a Krynn Minotaur's horns?

To clarify, I'm referring specifically to these [Krynn Minotaurs](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Waterborne_v3.pdf).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, unfortunately your horns don't get to benefit from Ki-Empowered Strikes. Ki-Empowered Strikes are:

> Starting
>   at
>   6th
>   level,
>   your
>   unarmed
>   strikes
>   count
>   as
>   magical
>   for
>   the
>   purpose
>   of
>   overcoming
>   resistance
>   and
>   immunity
>   to
>   nonmagical
>   attacks
>   and
>   damage.

Whereas the Minotaur's horns are described as:

> ***Horns.***
>    You are never unarmed. You are 
>   proficient with your horns, which are a melee 
>   weapon that deals 1d10 piercing damage. Your 
>   horns grant you advantage on all checks made to 
>   shove a creature, but not to avoid being shoved 
>   yourself.

This is pretty clear. Your horns are a melee weapon which you always have. Note that unarmed strikes are described as:

> Instead of
>   using a
>   weapon to
>   make a
>   melee weapon
>   attack, you
>   can use
>   an unarmed
>   strike: a
>   punch, kick,
>   head‑butt, or
>   similar forceful
>   blow 
>   (none of
>   which count
>   as weapons).

So your unarmed strike is explicitly something which you use instead of a weapon and doesn't count as one. Since your horns are a melee weapon, they can't be an unarmed strike. Since they're not an unarmed strike, they don't benefit from Ki-Empowered Strikes.

As a final note, consider that if the horns were meant to be a feature that modified unarmed strikes, there are already playable races that do this. The Aarakocra, from the [*Elemental Evil Player's Companion*](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/EE_PlayersCompanion.pdf), has this feature:

> ***Talons.*** You are proficient with your unarmed strikes,
>   which deal 1d4 slashing damage on a hit.

So if the Minotaur's Horns feature was meant to modify unarmed strikes, it would probably look similar to that.

Comment: Wait. Since you are never unarmed, does it mean a Minotaur can't be a monk?

Comment: @Cristol.GdM *Technically*, you can't use Martial Arts, no. (You can still be a Monk, you're just not good at it.) It's worth pointing out, though, horns aren't defined as simple *or* martial weapons - this is probably an editing mistake. If they were simple weapons, this wouldn't be a problem. (There's also a *really* finicky argument based around the word "wielding", but...eh.)

Comment: @Cristol.GdM Incidentally, that would make a pretty good question in itself.

Comment: @Miniman - It's a little strong to say you can't benefit from Martial Arts as a Minotaur because you happen to have horns. Especially considering the race was added after the PHB. Its far more likely that the horns are considered natural weapons the way a Dragonborn's breath *weapon* is.